# Raising elements in a vector to a power

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I am trying to input a vector and parameter p, which in turn should raise each element of the vector to the power p. So far I have tried mapping the numeric tower function power, but that has proved unsuccessful. What would be the easiest way to raise each element of a vector to a power p?

```
(defn p' [x p] 
        (map power x p))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like:

```
(defn compute [exp numbers]
  (map #(power exp %) numbers))
```

For more information, type the following in your REPL:

```
(doc map)
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Chiron's answer, you could also do with partial application:

```
(defn compute [exp numbers]
  (map (partial power exp) numbers))
```