# Writing the Lp norm function

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I'm attempting to write the Lp norm function as to generalize the standard L2 norm (Euclidean distance) used. Here is what I have come up with so far, given how I had written the L2 norm:

```
(defn foo [a b p]
     (reduce + (map (comp (map #(power a %) p) -) a b)))
```

However I am getting the error ClassCastException whenever I try to implement this function. Part of the interim code is from a previously asked question [Raising elements in a vector to a power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189258/raising-elements-in-a-vector-to-a-power) where the following code was provided:

```
(defn compute [exp numbers]
     (map #(power exp %) numbers))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider factoring your code.

First define the p-norm

```
(defn p-norm [p x] 
   (if (= p :infinity) 
     (apply max (for [xi x] (Math/abs xi)))
     (Math/pow 
       (reduce + (for [xi x] (Math/pow xi p))) 
       (/ 1 p))))
```

And then use the p-norm to define your p-metric

```
(defn p-metric [p x y] 
  (p-norm p (map - x y)))
```

Example

```
(p-metric 2 [0 0] [3 4])
;=> 5.0

(p-metric :infinity [0 0] [3 4])
;=> 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner (map):

```
(map #(power a %) p)
```

Returns a sequence and you can't feed that to (comp). 'comp' is for 'Function Composition'.

In the REPL:

```
(doc comp)
clojure.core/comp
([] [f] [f g] [f g h] [f1 f2 f3 & fs])
  Takes a set of functions and returns a fn that is the composition
  of those fns.  The returned fn takes a variable number of args,
  applies the rightmost of fns to the args, the next
  fn (right-to-left) to the result, etc.
```

Start breaking your code into smaller steps. (let) form is quite handy, don't be shy to use it.